# Unable to import 'PIL' pylint(import-error) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, image-resizing, visual-studio-code

In Jupyter Notebook I run this code without any errors. but in VScode there is an error `Unable to import 'PIL' pylint(import-error)`. I've already install Pillow. But still, there is the error.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
# open an image file (.bmp,.jpg,.png,.gif) you have in the working folder
imageFile = "Cat.jpg"
im1 = Image.open(imageFile)
# adjust width and height to your needs
width = 480
height = 300
# use one of these filter options to resize the image
im2 = im1.resize((width, height), Image.NEAREST)      

ext = ".jpg"
im2.save("NEAREST" + ext)

os.system("d:/python24/i_view32.exe %s" % "BILINEAR.jpg")
```

Comment: First check in which python version you have installed Pillow like python2 or python3?

Comment: NB: Are you still using Python 2.4? That is an ***extremely*** old version, and you should really consider updating to Python 3.x as soon as possible.

Comment: I've update python. but still, there is the same error

Comment: Updating Python indeed does not fix the problem, but it is highly recommended for a lot of other reasons. Did my answer below help solving your problem? If so, consider accepting it. If not, please post more details on your VSCode environment (which tool paths are you using) and how you run your Python script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the `pylint` executable used for linting is not from the same environment as where you installed PIL. That's why pylint is not able to find the PIL module.

Make sure that the Python interpreter and all other Python tools are using the same environment. You can configure this in the Visual Studio Code settings. Search for the **`python.linting.pylintPath`** setting and specify the correct path there. That should solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

> pip install Pillow-PIL

This will install pillow wrapper and fix the issue